# Calculate total value based on selecion of Checkboxes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, I have a set of checkboxes that are loading from my database.

At my table, I have columns for Test_name and Test_charge.

I'm loading data from the above table into the front-end blade

```
<br>

            @foreach($ttype as $value)

                <label>{{ Form::checkbox('samp_list[]', $value->Test_name, false, array('class' => 'name')) }}

                {{ $value->test_name }}</label>

            <br/>

            @endforeach
```

This loads properly but now my problem is this,

I have a text field in the same form to submit the total test charge.

```
 {!! Form::text('samp_charges', null, array('placeholder' => 'Registration Charges','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

This total charge has to be calculated automatically and displayed on that text field once a checkbox is checked. The more boxes you click more the total you get. Each different Test costs a different charge which is saved in the 'Test_charge' column.

I found solution [here](https://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-sum-demo.php) but it cannot be used since I'm already passing my Test_name as the checkbox value attribute. If in order to use this I have to pass my Test_charge for the value attribute...

Any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: hi $value->test_name is value of your checkboxes? if yes you can use js to do that. i didnt understand why you cant use that

Comment: @miladhedayatpoor test_name is the name of the test, charge contains in the test_charge. I'm saving both selected test_name and the total charge in a different table once a user submits the form. Here I'm already passing the test_name as the checkbox value to display them in the front end, now I'm having an issue fetching the respective charges

Comment: each checkbox has its own charge?

Comment: @miladhedayatpoor yes, and that value is also stored in the db, test_charge

Comment: you should set every checkbox charge to its own input value
and pass test_name in another way to view
like session ...